# Angular OpenLayers - Zoom to box with bounds

Tags: openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I tried to figure out how to zoom the map to box with bounds but couldn't find a good example.
I tried with

```
angular.extend($scope, {
        offset: 0,
        center: {
            lat: 30.0047,
            lon: 31.2586,
            bounds: [30.566461328125,
                     29.766565657014183,
                     31.950738671875005,
                     30.242264176913594]
        }
    });
```

How can I set themap to zoom to the bounding box without complicate conversion of the 4 bounds to (center, zoom)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want

```
map.getView().fit( 
    ol.proj.transformExtent([ x1, y1, x2, y2 ], 'EPSG:COORDS', 'EPSG:MAP'),
    map.getSize()
    );
```

This is after your map exists, not on initialization.

http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.View.html#fit

Comment: You forgot `map.getSize()`. So right answer would be `map.getView().fit(ol.proj.transformExtent( [ x1, y1, x2, y2 ], 'EPSG:COORDS', 'EPSG:MAP'), map.getSize());`. This is for OpenLayers v3.7 and above, and before was used function fitExtent instead fit. Just update your answer with this. Thank you ;)

Comment: Done, thanks for catching that. I added a link to the docs too